# Python Case Matching Input and Output

Tags: python, string

I'm doing the pig latin question that I'm sure everyone here is familiar with it. The only thing I can't seem to get is matching the case of the input and output. For example, when the user enters Latin, my code produces `atinLay`. I want it to produce `Atinlay`.

```
import string

punct = string.punctuation
punct += ' '
vowel = 'aeiouyAEIOUY'
consonant = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ'

final_word = input("Please enter a single word. ")
first_letter = final_word[:1]

index = 0

if any((p in punct) for p in final_word):
    print("You did not enter a single word!")
else:
    while index < len(final_word) and (not final_word[index] in vowel):
        index = index+1
    if any((f in vowel) for f in first_letter):
        print(final_word + 'yay')
    elif index < len(final_word):
        print(final_word[index:]+final_word[:index]+'ay')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [`str.title()`](http://docs.python/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title). Once you have done your piglatin conversion, you can use `title()` built-in function to produce the desired output, like so:

```
>>> "atinLay".title()
'Atinlay'
```

To check if a string is lower case, you can use [`str.islower()`](http://docs.python/3/library/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower). Take a peek at the docs.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that if the user enters all lowercase, then I don't want the output capitalized.

Comment: @ChristopherFlach That's simple. Just use str.islower(), which is also built-in.

Answer (score 0):

simply use the built in string functions.

```
s = "Hello".lower()
s == "hello"
s = "hello".upper()
s == "HELLO"
s = "elloHay".title()
s == "Ellohay"
```

Comment: or "hello world'.title() = Hello World

Comment: There you go, even better.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that if the user enters all lowercase, then the output should stay in lowercase.
Examples
Latin -> Atinlay
latin -> atinlay